# Ammed a column in pandas dataframe based on the string value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text column with chat information, I want to pass in a list of words that if they appear in that text column will ammend the error column to 1 and 0 if the words do not appear:

```
chatid text                  card_declined booking_error website_error
401    hi my card declined..        0              0             0
402    you website crashed..        0              0             0
403    hi my card declined..        0              0             0

for example 

carddeclined = ['card declined', 'Card error']

for i in df[df['textchat'].str.contains('|'.join(carddeclined),na=False)]:
    df['card declined'] = 1

This currently just returns all card declined rows with 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign converted boolean Series to integers, because some upercase values in list is added `case=False` parameter in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
carddeclined = ['card declined', 'Card error']

df['card_declined'] = df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(carddeclined),
                                              na=False, 
                                              case=False).astype(int)
print (df)
   chatid                   text  card_declined  booking_error  website_error
0     401  hi my card declined..              1              0              0
1     402  you website crashed..              0              0              0
2     403  hi my card declined..              1              0              0
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael thank you for your help. I need the df['card_declined'] column to be assigned the value 0 or 1 based on the conditional statement. This is my sticking point really

Comment: @odevney - I forget add `.astype(int)`

Comment: Hi Jezrael So that has just added new columns called whatever is in the list. I just need the existing df['card_declined'] column to be amended to 1 if any of those words appear in the df['textchat'] column. I hope that is a bit clearer. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @odevney - so need assign only one column? Can you check eduted answer?

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Yes I just need the df['card_declined'] column updated to a 1 if any of the words found in the carddeclined list passed in appears in the df['textchat'] column

Comment: @odevney - if not working like need, is possible add some data sample for explain problem?

Comment: Apologies Jezrael your updated code worked perfectly thank you so much! I have tried about 20 different ways to get this working....